# Create a tridiagonal matrix

Tags: r, matrix, diagonal

I need to program R with a matrix which has (1+x^2) down the leading diagonal (the constant value of x is given earlier in the program) and x down the diagonals on either side of the leading diagonal, and 0 everywhere else. I hope that makes sense! Can anyone tell me how I would program that, I can only find how to enter values on the leading diagonal and not any other diagonals. It is a 71x71 matrix so I cannot enter it manually!

Comment: There must be some way it can be done, surely you can input any matrix you need into R?

Comment: This answer shows how to get the sub- and super-diagonals. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9885186/1017276. But as @G.Grothendieck points out, the diagonal has 71 entries, and the sub- and super-diagonals each have 70 entries.  Attempting a replacement on them will, at best, depend on recycling or, at worst, cause an error.

Comment: I'm not asking for a length n sub or superdiagonal. I think you are over complicating my question.

Comment: Then you may need to provide a small sample matrix (say 6x6) showing what the desired output ought to look like.

Comment: My interpretation is that `x` is a constant of length 1. OP says *"the value of x is given earlier in the program"*. If we set, say, `x = 2`, I think OP wants `1 + x^2 = 5` on the diagonal, and `x = 2` on the super and sub diagonals. (My best guess - it would be nice if @Charlotte would confirm, with a nice example).

Comment: That's correct yes, didn't mean to over complicate it I simply meant a value x :) you're all vastly overestimating my R capabilties haha!

Comment: So the question should read that `x` is a *scalar* computed previously in the program.

Answer (score 4):

### Scalar

If `x` is a scalar and `n` is the common row and column dimension then:

```
# test inputs
x <- 10
n <- 5

m <- diag(1+x^2, n)
m[abs(row(m) - col(m)) == 1] <- x
```

giving:

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  101   10    0    0    0
[2,]   10  101   10    0    0
[3,]    0   10  101   10    0
[4,]    0    0   10  101   10
[5,]    0    0    0   10  101
```

### Vector

If `x` is a vector then since the sub-diagonal and super-diagonal are one element shorter than the diagonal we need to specify them separately -- here the latter two are specified as `y`.

```
# test values for diagonal and sub/super diagonals
x <- 1:5
y <- 11:14

m <- diag(x)
m[row(m) - col(m) == 1] <- m[row(m) - col(m) == -1] <- y
```

giving:

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1   11    0    0    0
[2,]   11    2   12    0    0
[3,]    0   12    3   13    0
[4,]    0    0   13    4   14
[5,]    0    0    0   14    5
```

### Note

Note that such a matrix is referred to as a tridiagonal matrix and searching for *R tridiagonal* will turn up some relevant links.

Comment: Thank you so much that's exactly what I needed! I've never coded before I just have to do this R project for my Masters *rolls eyes*.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a sparse band matrix:

```
# test inputs
x <- 10
n <- 5

library(Matrix)
M <- bandSparse(n, n, #dimensions
                (-1):1, #band, diagonal is number 0
                list(rep(x, n-1), 
                     rep(1+x^2, n), 
                     rep(x, n-1)))
#5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#
#[1,] 101  10   .   .   .
#[2,]  10 101  10   .   .
#[3,]   .  10 101  10   .
#[4,]   .   .  10 101  10
#[5,]   .   .   .  10 101
```

It can be coerced to a dense matrix easily if necessary:

```
as.matrix(M)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]  101   10    0    0    0
#[2,]   10  101   10    0    0
#[3,]    0   10  101   10    0
#[4,]    0    0   10  101   10
#[5,]    0    0    0   10  101
```

Answer (score -1):

The `diagonals` package might get you close (but not all the way) with the `fatdiag` function. Here's an example of how to create a 12x12 matrix and fill the area around the diagonal with a value:

```
> library(diagonals)
> m <- matrix(0, nrow=12, ncol=12)
> fatdiag(m, steps=3) <- 999
> m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,]  999  999  999  999    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
 [2,]  999  999  999  999    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
 [3,]  999  999  999  999    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
 [4,]  999  999  999  999    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0  999  999  999  999    0     0     0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0  999  999  999  999    0     0     0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0  999  999  999  999    0     0     0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0  999  999  999  999    0     0     0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  999   999   999   999
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  999   999   999   999
[11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  999   999   999   999
[12,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  999   999   999   999
```

You can also specify `size`, which may be more helpful for you... it will fill that many cells around the diagonal:

```
> m <- matrix(0, nrow=12, ncol=12)
> fatdiag(m, size=2) <- 999
> m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,]  999  999    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
 [2,]  999  999    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
 [3,]    0    0  999  999    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
 [4,]    0    0  999  999    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0  999  999    0    0    0     0     0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0  999  999    0    0    0     0     0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0  999  999    0     0     0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0  999  999    0     0     0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  999   999     0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  999   999     0     0
[11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0   999   999
[12,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0   999   999
```

When this is done, you should be able to use the methods you are using to fill the diagonal with the desired value. (Since 71 isn't divisible by anything, you may have to create a 72x72 and then chop off the ends.) Without knowing the context of your problem, it's hard to assess how much kludginess is acceptable :)

Comment: I don't think this satisfies the requirements of the question.  Notice that `m[3,2]` and `m[2,3]`, for example, are not populated with a value.